# Como salvar tabelas com relacionamento no Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5

Vou colocar um pequeno exemplo para explicar o meu problema.

Tabelas:

```
main
itens
```

As duas tem relacionamento, uma `main` tem vários `itens`.

O que estou fazendo para salvar:

```
...
$main = $this->main->create($postCreate);
foreach ($postCreate['itens'] as $item){
    $item['main_id'] = $main->id;
    $this->itens->create($item);
}
...
```

Funciona, porem se ocorrer algum erro na hora de salvar os itens, é salvar o `main` sem os itens ou faltando alguns itens, queria salvar tudo, e se desse algum erro não salvar nada.

Como salvar tabelas com relacionamento no Laravel?

Comment: Esquece o ciclo, tenta `$main->items()->insert($postCreate['itens']);`, não precisas de `$item['main_id'] = $main->id` . Esse código está no controller?

Comment: Você pode usar **Transactions** para isso. Segue o link: [Laravel - Database Transactions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database#database-transactions)
Assim ou todas as operação serão persistidas, ou nenhuma será.

Comment: @Miguel o comando ´insert´ funcionou, porem eu não pude remover o ´$item['main_id'] = $main->id´, e de qualquer forma, quando da erro ele salva o ´main´ da mesma forma

Comment: Sim @GeekSilva, bem observado, para coisas sérias teria de ser isso mesmo

Comment: @WictorChaves, nesse caso transactions são o caminho. Mas supostamente não deverias de inserir o `main_id` no `$item`, https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method

Comment: Usando o insert ele não preenche automaticamente os campos created_at updated_at.

Comment: podes `createMany`, como aí nos docs eles demonstram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi da seguinte forma

Importei a seguinte classe:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

E coloquei meu código dentro de `transaction`:

```
return DB::transaction(function () use ($campos){
    return $this->meuMetodo($campos);
});
```

Desta forma todas as transações que estiverem dentro de `meuMetodo` só serão realmente salvas se todas derem verdadeiras.